# Mapping functions having 2 parameters to Zipdataset having 2 columns

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, tf.keras

I am using `tensorflow` and I'm going to use `tensorflow.keras` in CNN algorithm `categorical_crossentropy` for automatic speech recognition (`ASR`) and then further RNN to be used.

I have to run `data=data.map(preprocess)` but its throwing the error `AssertionError: dtype must be provided in graph mode`

Then after solving it, I have to make sure the final shape of Zipdataset should be of 4D-tensor instead of 3D-tensor which I get after uncommenting the 3 lines in data pipeline

After this I have to make sure that one-hot encoding of labelled text is compatible in CNN architechture for further run...please can anyone guide me through this, I'm literally new to tensorflow and ML,DL and I dont have time to read documentation

```
#DATA PIPELINE
# tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
data = data.map(preprocess) 
# data,label = preprocess(df_val_train)     #has 616 files .mp3
# data = tf.expand_dims(data, axis=0) 
# data = data.map(lambda filename, label: preprocess(filename,label))
data = data.cache()                             #output is 616
data = data.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)           #616
data = data.batch(10)                           #62
data = data.prefetch(2)                         #62              
len(data)

train = data.take(40)
test = data.skip(40).take(22)

samples= train.as_numpy_iterator().next()
# samples_4d = tf.expand_dims(samples, axis=0)
samples.shape
```

I tried changing functions and modified as desire output, added extra code lines ,changed whole when needed ,took help from chatgpt but it seems I may need help

```
def load_wav_16k_mono(filename):
    res = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor(filename)
    # Convert to tensor and combine channels 
    tensor = res.to_tensor()
    tensor = tf.math.reduce_sum(tensor, axis=1) / 2 
    # Extract sample rate and cast
    sample_rate = res.rate
    sample_rate = tf.cast(sample_rate, dtype=tf.int64)
    # Resample to 16 kHz
    wav = tfio.audio.resample(tensor, rate_in=sample_rate, rate_out=16000)
    return wav

dfvaltrain_fn = df_val_train['filename'].tolist()
dfvaltrain_txt = df_val_train['text'].tolist()
dfvaltrain_fn_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dfvaltrain_fn)
dfvaltrain_txt_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(sequences_padded)
data = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dfvaltrain_fn_dataset, dfvaltrain_txt_dataset))

def preprocess(file_path,label): 
    wav = load_wav_16k_mono(file_path)
    wav = wav[:20000]
    zero_padding = tf.zeros([20000] - tf.shape(wav), dtype=tf.float32)
    wav = tf.concat([zero_padding, wav],0)
    spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(wav, frame_length=320, frame_step=32)
    spectrogram = tf.abs(spectrogram)
    spectrogram = tf.expand_dims(spectrogram, axis=2)
    return spectrogram,label
```

Answer (score 0):

A lambda function can take any number of arguments but can only have one expression. Try it; it will resolve your issue.

```
data = data.map(lambda x: preprocess(x))
```

Comment: If x is a tuple of 2 things, shouldn't it be `data.map(lambda x: preprocess(*x))` or `data.map(lambda x: preprocess(x[0], x[1]))` to split the elements to the 2 function parameters?

Comment: I have used the techniques you're suggesting but its doesn't accepts until assertion error is satisfied. And from where I have to start taking care of graph...